# How do I simulate the physics of hitting a ball, badminton or flipping a pancake in Cocos2dX?

Tags: android, c++, ios, physics, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a game on cocos2d - X in C++ I want to simulate the physics of slapping an object similar to that of a beach ball or badminton.

This flash game is an example of what I'm trying to do.
http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/622566

Answer (score 0):

These links can help you out please go through them thoroughly

[Chipmunk](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Chipmunk)

[Using Physics in Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics)

[Box2D](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Box2D)

Hope this make you understand basics of physics in cocos2d-x.

Also check http://www.raywenderlich.com/ for beginner's tutorials.